# Filter jhipster users by role in UserService

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to filter users in jhipster by specific role. Would that filter come in the UserService class, essentially, a getNonAdminUsers method?  By default, the UserService calls getAllManagedUsers, which basically returns every user but me.  That's fine, but my goal is to return everyone who is not a ROLE_ADMIN user.
here's the existing "core".

`@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Page<UserDTO> getAllManagedUsers(Pageable pageable) {
return userRepository.findAllByLoginNot(pageable,Constants.ANONYMOUS_USER).map(UserDTO::new); }`

Comment: Have you considered using Spring Security `@PostAuthorize`  annotation in REST controller? See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#el-access

Answer (score 2):

As per previous suggestion
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/55768707/16699263)

in **UserRepository.java**

```
...
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;
...
Page<User> findAll(Specification<User> where, Pageable pageable);
```

in **UserService.java**

```
...
public Specification<User> isNotAdmin(Authority role) {
        return (obj, cq, cb) -> cb.isNotMember(role, obj.get("authorities"));
    }
```

in **UserResource.java**

```
...
import it.myagency.myproject.repository.AuthorityRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;
import it.myagency.myproject.domain.Authority;
...
    public UserResource(........., AuthorityRepository authorityRepository) {
...
        this.authorityRepository = authorityRepository;//dependency injection
    }
...
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @GetMapping("/notadmins")
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserDTO>> getAllUsersNotAdmin(Pageable pageable) {
        Authority admin = authorityRepository.findById(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN).get();
        final Page<UserDTO> page = userRepository.findAll(Specification.where(userService.isNotAdmin(admin)), pageable).map(UserDTO::new);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest(), page);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it's the best method

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Page<UserDTO> getAllManagedUsers(Pageable pageable) {
    Optional<User> userOnline = getUserWithAuthoritiesByLogin(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().get());
    Page<UserDTO> userRepo = userRepository.findAllByLoginNot(pageable, Constants.ANONYMOUS_USER).map(UserDTO::new);
    if(userOnline.get().getId() < 4)
    {
        return userRepo;
    }else {
        List<UserDTO> userList = new ArrayList<UserDTO>();
        userList.addAll(userRepo.getContent());
        Predicate<UserDTO> predicate = p-> p.getId() < 4;
        userList.removeIf(predicate);
        return new PageImpl<UserDTO>(userList, new PageRequest(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize()),userList.size());

    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be implemented using Specification (org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification);

First add a new method signature in your UserRepository

```
Page<User> findAll(Specification<User> where, Pageable pageable);
```

Then in you UserService add specification:

```
static Specification<User> isNotAdmin(Authority role) {
    return (obj, cq, cb) -> cb.isNotMember(role, obj.get("authorities"));
}
```

Then modify your method to filter by the Role you want to exclude:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Page<UserDTO> getAllManagedUsers(Pageable pageable) {
    Authority admin = authorityRepository.findById(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN).get();
    return userRepository.findAll(Specification.where(isNotAdmin(admin)), pageable).map(UserDTO::new);
}
```